# Package Caption Error Please help

Tags: captions

Dear Friends,
             Greetings, I have one error with my latex code. Kindly help me to remove this error.

This is the error message

> package caption error: something's wrong perhaps a missing \caption

I am putting MWE. Thanks

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage[monochrome]{color}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{empheq}
\makeatletter  %highlight
\AtBeginDocument{\let\hl\@firstofone}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Apneafft}
                \caption{Power spectrum in Apnea case \cite{Drinnan2000}}
                \label{Apneafft}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{normalfft}
                \caption{Power spectrum in normal case \cite{Drinnan2000}}
                \label{normalfft}
        \end{subfigure}
         \caption{Power spectrum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you provide is no minimal working example. Reducing your code to one yields this, and shows that the relevant part of the code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering\large A
                \caption{Power spectrum in Apnea case}
                \label{Apneafft}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering\large B
                \caption{Power spectrum in normal case}
                \label{normalfft}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Power spectrum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please work your way from here to find, what causes your problems, so that we may help you further.

Further, you load `wrapfig` and `float` twice in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. The given code works fine in the document class article but when I use the \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}, It shows the mentioned error. It means the problem is with the class file?

Comment: @Sohail So it seems then. Where does this file come from? Do you have to use it?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: svjour3 is a class provided by Springer Verlag/Springer Open, see http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK, but then I could very well imagine that they do not want subfigures to be used. This is the case in most journals, where multi-part figures should be submitted as one composite image. So, either the OP wants to submit to Springer, in which case he should stick to their rules because otherwise they will send back his manuscript anyways. Or he is writing something else (report, thesis, whatever), in which case it makes no sense to use a Springer class and not to use a standard or KOMA class.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: Well, most likely they don't like the subfigures. The problem is, that those publishing companies do their job for decades/centuries and stick to a layout since their beginning. They cast their layout into LaTeX files (if that's true at all) and use LaTeX techniques of the late 80s or early 90s and rarely change them. That's why the layouts and class files look awful. Once an author managed to cope with the publisher LaTeX file they stick to the company rather than to switch.

Comment: Thank you. Are you suggesting to remove the subfigure and plot them separately?

Comment: @Sohail I suggest to built a composite image manually, e.g. in Photoshop/Illustrator/InkScape, so that you have only one image file (with subimages) to include in your tex document. You can insert labels (e.g. 'A', 'B' manually when constructing this image to refer to in the caption). This is how it is commonly done for manuscripts, because subfigures created directly in LaTeX are a mess for the typesetting office, espacially when the final article is not typeset in Latex (as is the case in the majority of journals, Springer publications included).